# Haskell ad package

Tags: haskell, automatic-differentiation

I want to use the ad automatic differentiation package for learning neural network weights in Haskell. I have found some [functions](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/ad/3.4/doc/html/Numeric-AD-Newton.html#g:2) that might just have what I need, however I can't figure out what they expect as the first parameter. It must be the function to optimize, but I don't know what form exactly.
They have signatures like this:

```
gradientDescent :: (Traversable f, Fractional a, Ord a) => (forall s. Mode s => f (AD s a) -> AD s a) -> f a -> [f a]
```

I have found out `forall s.` means something named an existential quantifier but nothing more.
My question is, that how could I pass my cost function with a signature like `cost :: [Double] -> Double` (it takes the list of weights) to this library?

Comment: So is your question "What does `forall s.` mean in Haskell?"?  Or is your question "How do I use the ad package?"? When you post on SO it's good to actually state the question.

Comment: I edited the post to clearly state my question

Comment: Note: Here that 'forall' is actually a "universal" quantifier, not an existential. It is only used for existential purposes on data constructors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the first argument is a function on any traversable of `AD` to a single `AD`. For the traversable, we can substitute in something like a list to start with. That function must be polymorphic in mode. So let's ignore that and just not do something that specifies a mode! This function is obviously the thing we're optimizing. The next argument is the initial value we pass in. We'll also call that a list for now. And the result is a list of steadily more optimized choices for improved guesses at our target.

Note that `AD s a` is an instance of `Num` and `Fractional` for all modes `s`, as long as `a` is `Num` and `Fractional`. So just write a polymorphic function from a list of integers to a single integer, pass in an initial state, and the function you provided will optimize it for you.

I.e. don't specify your cost function as over doubles, but specify it as polymorphic over any `Num` and `Fractional`, and let the library take care of the rest!

You may prefer to get used to this style by trying other, more basic functions such as `diff` first.

Comment: Thank you, I should have thought about overloading, since it's the base of AD.